# How to execute SQL SELECT query and see the results?

Tags: widgets, query

I want to run a SELECT query on the Wordpress database and get the results on the screen.
Any widget which does it?

Comment: The title is misleading, it sounds more like how to run a query in php and print the results, which is what the answer gives. If you want a plugin (not a widget) then it should be "what plugin allows me to run select sql queries?" and you get this https://wordpress.org/plugins/run-sql-query/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/sql-executioner/

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [$wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), it does exactly what you want:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

Try to avoid SQL queries for basic operations though. WordPress offers you many convenience functions for 80% of the tasks you would every come up with. They provide a nicer interface and preserve upwards compatibility. 
For example to get posts from the DB you could use the [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or the [get_posts() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply.
I do not have access to php files right now. I would prefere to do this via a widget. Any widget that offers this?