# How to show result of sql query in a page?

Tags: mysql, sql, mssql

I have a table in the same DB that I have a WordPress page and I want to show in the land page the count of total of rows  and then I need an another page that show the information of this table , How can I do this?

And I want to be easy to add, for example that I can add the count or the information like presing edit page and in the add section there is something like "Total count" or "Total information".
I see in add menú that I have some widgets like "Shortcode", "Categories", "Archives", "Latest comments", "Latest Posts" how can I add a custom widget here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute SQL SELECT query and see the results?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63958/how-to-execute-sql-select-query-and-see-the-results)

Comment: I edit the question to add more information

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I follow this tutorial:

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/

And complimented with this:
https://gist.github.com/mattheu/7cf235b4f932de891bc21cb5f3ff3de6